# Rotate UILabel in UIStackView

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, swift3

I try to rotate a UILabel but I can't make it work.

My code:

```
import UIKit

class KomischeKaestchenView: UIView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        let height = frame.height
        let width = frame.width

        let beschreibungsLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height * 1 / 9))
        beschreibungsLabel.text = "Dekubitus"
        let spaceView = UIView()
        let weitereEinschätzungen = UILabel()
        weitereEinschätzungen.text = "weitere Einschätzungen notwendig"
        weitereEinschätzungen.font = weitereEinschätzungen.font.withSize(8)
        weitereEinschätzungen.numberOfLines = 0

        let mittelStackView = UIStackView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width / 2, height: height * 2 / 9))
        mittelStackView.axis = .horizontal
        mittelStackView.distribution = .fillEqually
        mittelStackView.alignment = .fill
        mittelStackView.addArrangedSubview(spaceView)
        mittelStackView.addArrangedSubview(weitereEinschätzungen)

        let stackViewJaNein = UIStackView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width / 2, height: height * 1 / 9))
        stackViewJaNein.axis = .horizontal
        stackViewJaNein.distribution = .fillEqually
        stackViewJaNein.alignment = .fill
        let jaLabel = UILabel()
        jaLabel.text = "ja"
        jaLabel.font = jaLabel.font.withSize(12)
        let neinLabel = UILabel()
        neinLabel.text = "nein"
        neinLabel.font = jaLabel.font.withSize(12)
        let jaLabel1 = UILabel()
        jaLabel1.text = "ja"
        jaLabel1.font = jaLabel.font.withSize(12)
        let neinLabel1 = UILabel()
        neinLabel1.text = "nein"
        neinLabel1.font = jaLabel.font.withSize(12)
        stackViewJaNein.addArrangedSubview(jaLabel)
        stackViewJaNein.addArrangedSubview(neinLabel)
        stackViewJaNein.addArrangedSubview(jaLabel1)
        stackViewJaNein.addArrangedSubview(neinLabel1)

        let obererStackViewLinks = UIStackView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width * 4 / 10, height: height * 4 / 9))
        obererStackViewLinks.axis = .vertical
        obererStackViewLinks.distribution = .fillProportionally
        obererStackViewLinks.alignment = .fill
        obererStackViewLinks.addArrangedSubview(beschreibungsLabel)
        obererStackViewLinks.addArrangedSubview(mittelStackView)
        obererStackViewLinks.addArrangedSubview(stackViewJaNein)

       //here is the stupid label
        let beratungsLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width / 10, height: height * 4 / 9))

    //that is the transformation
            beratungsLabel.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: -CGFloat.pi / 2)

        beratungsLabel.text = "Beratung"
        beratungsLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

        let obereStackViewRechts = UIStackView()
        obereStackViewRechts.axis = .horizontal
        obereStackViewRechts.distribution = .fillProportionally
        obereStackViewRechts.alignment = .fill
        obereStackViewRechts.addArrangedSubview(obererStackViewLinks)
        obereStackViewRechts.addArrangedSubview(beratungsLabel)
        print(beratungsLabel.frame)
        beratungsLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width / 10, height: height * 4 / 9)
        print(beratungsLabel.frame)

        let obereStackView = UIStackView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height * 4 / 9))
        obereStackView.axis = .horizontal
        obereStackView.distribution = .fillEqually
        obereStackView.alignment = .fill
        obereStackView.addArrangedSubview(UIView())
        obereStackView.addArrangedSubview(obereStackViewRechts)

        self.addSubview(obereStackView)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

So its all about "beratungsLabel". If I dont rotate the label it looks like this:

[image: before rotation]

The text "Beratung" only need to be vertical and it would be like I want it. But after the rotation it looks like this:

[image: after rotatio]

I tried to swap height and width. But it doesnt matter. Its always the same result. What is wrong with my code.

Kindly Regards!

Comment: I would try to rotate the label and then put it in a host view that gets added to the stack view.

Comment: Fix your label width to fit content then rotate 'width /10' is way too small?

Comment: Hi, Were you able to fix this? I am having the same issue with `UIPickerView`.